# will the php readdir function work with 1 million files in a single directory?

Tags: php, file, readdir

I am writing a script that needs to scan through a large amount of files (potentially up to 1 million) in a single directory (ext4). I am planning on using the PHP readdir function to create the list.

Since I don't have that amount of files in the directory yet, I don't know if it will work. I know 'ls' and such don't work on that amount of files, but I don't need them to.

So, the question is really only ...will PHP readdir work on 1 million files?

Comment: Can you just write a script that creates that number of files and test it?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you have so many files? It will kill your performance. Can't you group the data somehow? Or store it in a database?
I can't really see how one million files in a sigle directory would make sense. The fragmentation would be enormous.
Please give an example of the file you are storing.

Comment: They are images and the IDs of every single image will be stored in a mySQL database, which is there the application will later find every image to output, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Store the images inside the database, that's your solution.

Comment: or hash the files and group by the first letter of the hash like mediawiki does

Answer (score 0):

My answer to my own question, if anyone is wondering, is IT WORKS. I created a script to create 1 million random files and successfully ran the readdir function.